How to configure machine certificate for netplan openconnect vpn
How do you configure a machine certificate for a openconnect vpn in netplan?
I have looked at the documentation and can only see options for client-certificates. I need to use a certificate from a smartcard as well.

with openconnect it's called --mca-certificate
with network-manager it is called mcacert


What version of Ubuntu are you using?

This is for kubuntu 24.04 that apperently uses Netplan as a abstraction on top of NetworkManager i guess ubuntu 24.04 do as well?

I kind of got solved, you can add it by appending vpn.mcacert in netplan yaml, but apparently the network-manager gui in plasma 5 dont care about that property and wont use it for its connection
